# Winapi IsDialogMessage() doesn't navigate to multiline edit

Tags: winapi

I have window with some edit controls, but IsDialogMessage() skips multiline edit. Can anyone guide me on how to change this?

```
        n=WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_AUTOHSCROLL;

        if(!readonly) 
            n|=WS_TABSTOP;

        if(multi) 
            n=WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|WS_VSCROLL; 
        if(readonly)
            n|=ES_READONLY;

        obj=CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, "EDIT", "", n,(int)x, (int)y, (int)w, (int)h, parent, (HMENU)id, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);
```

message loop:

```
    while (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {

        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) break;

        if(msg.hwnd!=hwnd){
            HWND obj;
            obj=GetParent(msg.hwnd);
            if(obj){
                if(IsDialogMessage(obj,&msg))
                    continue;
            }
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
        }

        DispatchMessage(&msg);
     }
```

Comment: Please elaborate - that is quite ambiguous. What do you mean with "`IsDialogMessage` skips multiline edit"? The function returns `FALSE` for messages from that control, or something else?

Comment: All edit contols have WS_TABSTOP.

Comment: And your tab order is correct? Please post code (in this case, either the dialog resource or the code that creates the dialog, if you are creating it programmatically).

Comment: All edit contols have WS_TABSTOP. But multiline contol does not get focus when I press Tab key. So, IsDialogMessage dont run for multiline edit control, and so does not return True or False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `if(!readonly) n |= WS_TABSTOP` line you correctly set the tab stop style for your control.

On the very next line, in case of `multi`, you override `n` with a set of flags that do *not* contain the style `WS_TABSTOP`.

Switch the order of the first two `if`s.

Answer (score 0):

Complement to jlahd's answer:

Having a  `if(!readonly)` and some lines further a `if(readonly)` is bad style. ANd it's also better do have a `else`for the test on `multi`. Like below:

```
    if(multi) 
        n=WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_MULTILINE|ES_AUTOVSCROLL|WS_VSCROLL; 
    else
        n=WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|ES_AUTOHSCROLL;

    if(!readonly) 
        n|=WS_TABSTOP;
    else
        n|=ES_READONLY;


    obj=CreateWindowEx(....
```